# Turn an iso file into a live linux

Tags: 18.04, isolinux

I have created an iso file using mkisofs from a directory that contain a linux system structure like:

```
cs50@BaitLinux:~/idefs$ ls
bin   build  dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  data   etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
```

Now I want to make it bootable as a Ubuntu 18.04 live system.

Comment: Not enough effort was made to research this issue via Ubuntu forums and docs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to burn your image file to a CD/DVD or USB stick which you can then use as a live system, but the exact details depend on which OS you're currently using. Fortunately, all of the major OSes make this process rather straightforward:

USB:

- Windows: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview
- macOS: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
- Ubuntu: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview

DVD:

- Windows: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/burn-a-dvd-on-windows#1-overview
- macOS: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/burn-a-dvd-on-macos#1-overview
- Ubuntu: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu#1-getting-started